# JavaScript Do/While Loop Infinitely Looping

Tags: javascript

I know this is potentially a common question however I believe the logic and the code appear correct, yet it still seems to loop until the browser crashes.

```
$("#orderview").click(function(){
    do {
        $(".row1").clone().appendTo(".cardbox");
        var i = $( "listrow" ).length;
         }
    while (i < 10);
});
```

My function is creating Listrow class DIV's until there are 10 of them. My HTML starts with 1 DIV.

```
<div class="listrow news" id="row-a">
    <div class="l-padding floatleft">
        <div id="redditThumbnail"></div>
        <div class="articleheader news">
            <p class="mediatitle alignleft" id="redditTitle">
            </p>
            <p class="mediumtext floatleft alignleft">
                Submitted by
            </p>
            <div id="redditUsername"></div>
            <div class="half floatright">
                <p class="mediatext floatright s-color bold h-s-margin">
                    TEST
                </p>
                <p class="mediatext floatright p-color bold">
                    ACTION
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The logic behind my attempted JS was:

1. Clone the first DIV
2. Check how many "Listrow" class DIVs are present
3. If there are < 10 Listrow DIV's then restart the loop and clone
   another

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: I don't see a div with a class `row1` and your forgot the `.` for `listrow` length. I also don't think that'll work the way you think it might. Why not just use a for loop and be done?

Comment: your html code is missing some stuff you're using in your code, you're getting an infinite loop because of this line var i = $("listrow").length;. you're selecting the element (listrow) which doesn't exist and its returning 0

Comment: Hi, I apologize I copied the wrong DIV. I have another div with the correct "row1" class ended. Thats a good point. So you're suggesting just using a loop 10 times? I honestly hadnt thought of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change :

```
var i = $( "listrow" ).length;
```

to :

```
var i = $( ".listrow" ).length;
```

Comment: $('#orderview .listrow') should be a lot more efficient than searching the whole Dom